# When I wipe my 2012 HP laptop what drivers do I need to reinstall

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, reinstall

I just wiped my old 2012 HP laptop and reinstalled Windows 7 Home Edition.

Below is HP drivers on HP.

I have a couple questions.

1. There are 9 network drivers. Which one do I need to install just to have basic wifi connection? Because I'm assuming after getting Internet and doing Windows Update most of the drivers will get installed?
2. For the bios, chipset, driver storage, and firmware, do I need to reinstall those as well?

HP Pavilion dv6t-6c00 CTO

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-dv6-entertainment-notebook-pc-series/5214375/model/5214377

Comment: Avoid bios update. Check device manager for missing drivers. unless you know what the network chip is you will have to try them one at a time, they will not install if they do not apply to your chip, once you get one that does install, make a note of it for next time. Firmware is for the hard drive again check DM to see the model of your drive and compare to the offerings at HP, I never apply these. If any of the drivers do not apply to your system they will not install, so trying will do no harm.

Comment: You need to put your specific model into the HP Support site for your model and get all drivers including Chipset as it is a laptop. Done this way you should get all the drivers you need and not have duplicates. Your choice about BIOS. I use Lenovo machines and BIOS updates always work. You need to look at HP experience in this regard.